# SELECT max date from an inner join relation

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have 2 tables, `Staff` and `updateStaff`.

`Staff`:

```
Sid  Sname       
 ---|--------|
 1  | test1  |
 2  | test2  | 
 3  | test3  | 
 4  | test4  | 
 5  | test5  |
```

`updateStaff`:

```
Sid  Sprice    SDate    STime
---|--------|----------|--------|
1  | 150    |2015/10/09|6:35:00 |
2  | 250    |2015/10/10|5:21:00 |
3  | 75     |2015/11/11|17:30:00|
3  | 95     |2015/11/11|18:21:00|
4  | 300    |2015/12/12|2:25:00 |
```

I need result shows as:

```
Sid   SDate    STime     Sname   | Sprice     |
---|----------|--------|---------|------------
1  |2015/10/09|6:35:00 |test1    |150        |
2  |2015/10/10|5:21:00 |test2    |250        |
3  |2015/11/11|17:30:00|test3    |95         |
3  |2015/11/11|18:21:00|test3    |300        |
4  |2015/12/12|2:25:00 |test5    |NULL       |
```

In the other case, my below code show me both staff Id 3 on 2015/11/11 date.

```
SELECT  R.SId ,R.SName,R.Sprice
FROM (SELECT  Staff.SId ,Staff.SName,Sprice,updateStaff.SDate
      FROM Staff
        LEFT JOIN updateStaff ON Staff.SId = updateStaff.SId ) AS R
WHERE R.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM updateStaff WHERE updateStaff.SId =R.SId)
ORDER BY R.SId , R.SName
```

I need only the last staff's price order by date, time.

Comment: Your result looks meaningless. Why does record with Sid=4 have name=test5 and have empty price? Same for Sid=3 and name=test4.

Comment: just going by the given data and desired result... a simple join will give you what you want. the entry with two separate entries has the same date anyway so there is nothing actually being done by your select max(). Also that second column in your desired output seems strange. Its called sPrice but its showing the names, its also repeated under Sname

Comment: sorry my wrong . I corrected my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about sql server ce syntax, so I'm pretty sure there is a better way of doing it but you can do this:

```
SELECT  R.SId ,R.SName,R.Sprice
FROM (SELECT  Staff.SId ,Staff.SName,Sprice,updateStaff.SDate,updateStaff.stime
      FROM Staff
        LEFT JOIN updateStaff ON Staff.SId = updateStaff.SId ) AS R
WHERE R.stime = (SELECT MAX(stime) FROM updateStaff us WHERE us.SId =R.SId
      and us.sdate =(select max(sdate) from updateStaff us2 where us2.sid = us.sid))
ORDER BY R.SId , R.SName
```

Comment: thanks a lot your answer was correct and worked on sql server 2008 r2